# transparent background gif favicon appears with black square sometimes on chrome

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, firefox, background, favicon

With Wordpress my favicon which is a (verified) **background transparent gif** is displayed with **google Chrome and Opera**:

- in admin pages always normally
- in front-end pages always with a **black square background** -

**With Firefox or Edge it functions normally**

The favicon declarations are identical.

I think that the problem comes from any "parameter" linked to html, js or css content of pages and context. Something with changes the behavior of the browser (default value for ?)

I don't understand at all what can happend and I have no track to follow.

Thanks

Best regards

Trebly

Answer (score 0):

The black background is created during the upload. I have FTPed my GIFs to the correct folder and the transparency is preserved. You will need to check what names the GIFs are given first. A GIF with the name TEST.GIF will also be converted to TEST-300x300.GIF and TEST-150x150.GIF so these have to be created before you FTP your files. 300 & 150 are the size in pixels of the GIFs.